# Component doesn't resolve injection of $scope (angular 1.3.16)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, components

I have encountered a really weird error. I'm working on a project where we're using [John Papa's AngularJS](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) styleguide.

I have the following component-file, `my-profile.component.js`, attached to `app.mymodule`

**my-profile.component.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mymodule')
        .component('myProfile', { })
        .controller('MyProfileController', myProfileController);

    /*@ngInject*/
    function myProfileController($scope) {

        ...

    }
})();
```

The component is rendered using  in my view file.

`app.mymodule` is defined in `mymodule.module.js`

**mymodule.module.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mymodule', []);

})();
```

And `app` is defined in `app.modules.js`, where `app.mymodule` is set as an app dependency

**app.modules.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [

            ...
            'app.mymodule'
        ]);

})();
```

`my-profile.component.js` compiles to the following code

**my-profile.component.js** (compiled)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mymodule')
        .component('myProfile', { })
        .controller('MyProfileController', myProfileController);

    myProfileController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function myProfileController($scope) {

        ...

    }

})();
```

But for some reason, angular fails to inject the `$scope`-service, or any other service I attempt to inject. [It produces the following error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=1FilterProvider):

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 1FilterProvider <- 1Filter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/unpr?p0=1FilterProvider%20%3C-%201Filter
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7eNaNbundles%fjs%fvendor:63:12)
    at /layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:4031:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:4178:39)
    at /layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:4036:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:4178:39)
    at $get [as $filter] (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:16705:24)
    at Parser.filter (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:12234:19)
    at Parser.filterChain (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:12228:19)
    at Parser.primary (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:12079:22)
    at Parser.unary (/layout/js/vendor/angularjs-1.3.16/angular.js?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%fbundles%fjs%fvendor:12374:19)
```

I have another component in the same folder, attached to the same module, where **I can easily inject any service**. It looks as follows:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mymodule')
        .component('loginView', { })
        .controller('LoginViewController', loginViewController);



    /*@ngInject*/
    function loginViewController($scope, $location) {
        ...
    }

})();
```

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've spellchecked, doublechecked, started over on the component, attempted to $inject $scope on the controller manually, but to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here? :)

**EDIT**

As [rolandjitsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092007/rolandjitsu) pointed out, it was a problem in my view-file. I had used `ng-pattern` wrongfully, but was mislead by my own inability to interpret angular console-errors and a 'mildly' misleading error description in the angular docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems like you are missing a service provider called `1Filter`. Maybe a missing module or some files missing?

*Note: It has nothing to do with the `$scope`, it should not fail because of that.*